# Best workflow to refresh asp.net page using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, refresh

I am building a page in ASP.net with hundreds of questions that I'm parsing from xml.
I am able to render my first page of questions by rendering dynamic created radiobuttonlists to a placeholder called **sectionHolder**.

After javascript validation i want to move on to the next range of questions.
This is where I want to implement the best possible solution.

If i do a callback to my server and remove all controls from my **sectionHolder** followed by adding new questions, there is no change in my page. This is probably because i need to refresh my page.

The problem is when I refresh my page using javascript:

```
setTimeout("location.reload(true);", 250);
```

I lose everything not saved in my session object. (all variables declared in my class get resetted)
I am wondering if I really need to save all those variables I want to keep in that session object as I think it makes my code pretty messy. (constant casting from session to values, ...)

I know I can use a function to call my javascript from asp.net with generated html code, followed by changing the innerhtml of a div but I would like to keep on using my code that generates all the questions to the placeholder using asp's radiobuttonlist and listitem because all my other code is based on that.

Do I really have to put everything in my session or generate the javascript code myself or are there any other approaches here?

Thanks Alot!

---EDIT---

//Here is some code where I render my questions
(function to be called at start and by every page reload)

```
protected void AddQuestions()
{
    //lstsections is parsed from xml, it contains all the topics
    var cal = _lstSections.ElementAt(iCurrentSection);

    //limit questions to maxnumber
    var iNumQuestions = (cal._lstQuestions.Count < iNumQuestionsPerPage)
                            ? cal._lstQuestions.Count
                            : iNumQuestionsPerPage;

    for (int a = 0; a < iNumQuestions; a++)
    {
        //we offset our counter to determine page
        var iCurrentID = a + iCurrentQuestionStartIndex;

        //q is our current question
        var q = cal._lstQuestions.ElementAt(iCurrentID);
        //check if we dont have too many questions on this page
        var lbl = new Label() { Text = q.GetText(), ToolTip = q.GetToolTip() };
        var list = new RadioButtonList()
        {
            ID =  "RadioButtonList" + iCurrentID,
            RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal
        };

        list.Attributes.Add("runat", "Server");
        list.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "processText(" + (iCurrentID) + ")");
        list.EnableViewState = false;
        list.CssClass = "clsRadioButtonList";
        sectionHolder.Controls.Add(lbl);
        sectionHolder.Controls.Add(list);

        foreach (var opt in q._lstOptions)
        {
            var item = new ListItem() { Text = opt.Text, Value = opt.Value };
            list.Items.Add(item);
        }

        sectionHolder.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br>"));
    }
}
```

Comment: sure about what specific part?

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand the problem, I see no Session in your code. But as Mez said, you should user `UpdatePanels` with AJAX for partial page updates.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into jQuery Ajax? You can render your first set of questions on the first load, then use jQuery Ajax to make subsequent requests to the server and get the rest of your questions. Once your user has answered all the questions, they can submit the whole form with all the questions loaded and answered.

This approach is probably the best way to make clean partial postbacks to the server without losing everything on the page. And you can access the session object by using HttpContext.Current (since the methods you call using jQuery AJAX need to be static and decorated with the [WebMethod] attribute)

[Here's a great article](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) that explains how to implement jQuery AJAX in ASP.NET Web Forms

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I have some experience with jQuery and ajax. I would have to render and return all html code in a C#-string and apply that to the innerhtml of my div?

Is there any chance I could keep on rendering it to my placeholder (see sectionholder in the code) control and return the code it supposed to render? 
Something like "return sectionHolder.Controls.HtmlRenderCode"

Comment: Of course you can. You can use the .append() function in jquery to keep adding the HTML string returned from the server to your placeholder. Let me know if you need more info and I'll post a sample for you...

Comment: Thanks for all your help Mez!

I was a bit unclear in my reply(sorry!!). I need it on the csharp side not on the javascript side. So I need to have to content that the placeholder actually renders to the page after I removed all and added new questions..

Comment: I had to render my control:

        string htmlContentControl = RenderControl(sectionHolder);

        private static string RenderControl<T>(T c) where T : Control, new()
        {
            // get the text for the control
            using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
            using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
            {
                c.RenderControl(htw);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }

        public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
        {
            return;
        }

Comment: 1. I had to **add VerifyRenderingInServerForm** function to avoid error:
type ' ' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server"

2. I had to **change EnableEventValidation** in my aspx page
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  **EnableEventValidation = "false"** CodeBehind="page.aspx.cs" Inherits="page._Default" %>